# Selenium webdriver could not perform button click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I faced a problem of the button click issue by using selenium webdriver.
I'm trying to click the "like button" but it did not work.

Here is my selenium source code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=cwd+'chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://tw.carousell.com/')
time.sleep(5)
#carousell_login() my login part
time.sleep(5)
for_her = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/div/section[3]/div[2]/div[2]/a')
for_her.click()
time.sleep(5)
like_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/figure/div/button')
print like_button.get_attribute('outerHTML')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(like_button).click(like_button).perform()
```

[image]

This is the output:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pdt-card-like"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
```

It seems that I found that element. I had no idea why the click did not work.

Is there any advice for this issue?

Thanks!

========================================================================
By using Andersson's solution, it make the click action works!
Thanks for the tips!

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("button.btn.btn-default.pdt-card-like")[0].style.display="block";')
driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("button.btn.btn-default.pdt-card-like")[0].style.visibility="visible";')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-default pdt-card-like"]')[0].click()
```

Comment: this is not your output.

Comment: need you to show us your HTML as well

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: What you mean "didn't work"? Do you get any exceptions or just nothing happened?

Comment: My expectation was that the button was clicked and added 1 like for that item. But when I executed the code, there was nothing happened.

Comment: Need you to show what the error message and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Like" button is not visible initially, so you cannot just click on it- you should make if visible first, so try following code:

```
number = 0
driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("button.btn.btn-default.pdt-card-like")[number].style.display="block";')
driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("button.btn.btn-default.pdt-card-like")[number].style.visibility="visible";')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-default pdt-card-like"]')[number].click()
```

This should allow you to "like" first item. Set another `number` value to change target item

Comment: this actually hacks the HTML code; there has to be a way to make this button visible, like clicking a first button or something. hacking this HTML code may give him what he wants now, but it can break things down the track.

Comment: This is not a big hack :) It depends on OP goals. This code just make button be always visible, but not only if to hover to it. Same can be done with `ActionChains` but as I remember this module works not always as expected with `chromedriver`

Comment: @bowhey, Please accept this answer by putting checkmark under answer score (upvote/downvote totals)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to hover to the thumbnail before the like button will appear. Try to separate move_to_element and click into 2 separate methods and give a sleep in between.
Sorry, I don't know Python, but it should look like this.

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(like_button).perform()
sleep(1000)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(like_button).perform()
```

In case if it still does not work, you might want to change the element to move to be the thumbnail element instead. For ex:

```
image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="pdt-card-img"]')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(image).perform()
sleep(1000)
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(like_button).perform()
```

Note that the image element above might not be correct, because there are several of them on the html page. Make sure you select the right one.